# Solve the system (x1, x2, x3)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\left\{\begin{align}x_{1} + x_{2} +4x_{3} &= 1 \\  
3x_{1} +2x_{2} -5x_{3} &= -8
\end{align}\right.$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix} \quad \\ \quad \\ \quad \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So when I try to solve this, I turn it into an augmented/coefficient matrix. Then I row reduce. Which gives me the reduced matrix:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -13 & -10 \\  
0 & 1 & 17 & 11
\end{array}\right]$$

Then I turned this back into an equation
$$\begin{align*}
x_{1} + 0x_{2} -13 x_{3} &= -10 \\
0x_{1} + x_{2} +17 x_{3} &= 11
\end{align*}$$

Then basically I get that
$$\begin{align*}
x_{1} &= -10 + 13s \\  
x_{2} &= 11 - 17s
\end{align*}$$

The answer has $3$ rows per vector. So I'm just confused as to what goes into the $x_3$ spot for the row or if I even did this correctly.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: I am not sure how to do so. I tried my best

Comment: But the x1 is x sub one, but I don't know how to make it look like that

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a page that shows how to format mathematical symbols and operations for the site...

Comment: @KJay I've edited your question. If my interpretation is not correct, please feel free to edit it again, or simply revert back to the previous version. In either case, I would advise pressing "edit" to see how I've formatted your question. Have a play around with it, so you can take the opportunity to learn to do this for yourself.

Comment: While I'm here, when writing out the equations from the augmented matrix, it seems that $x_2$ appears in the first equation, when it shouldn't. Similarly for $x_1$ in the second equation.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this to learn how to do it next time

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to put the 0 in front of one

Comment: Add a row of zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, you've let $x_3$ be a free variable $s$. Hence, in addition to $x_1 = -10 + 13s$ and $x_2 = 11 - 17s$, you also have $x_3 = 0 + 1s$. That is,
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -10 \\ 11 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix} 13 \\ -17 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I'm still a little confused why does $x_{3}$ = 0 +1s

Comment: @KJay The method you're following, even if you don't completely understand it, is to take certain variables in your system of equation (specifically, ones corresponding to a column without pivots, in this case, just $x_3$) and make them free variables. By choosing a value of $x_3$, you obtain unique values for $x_1, x_2$ that produce a solution. Conversely, any solution must assign $x_3$ a value! So, we can parameterise all solutions by letting $x_3$ roam free over the reals.

Comment: @KJay Conventionally, we give our free parameters their own name, typically $t, s, r$, etc. You've called $x_3$ the free parameter $s$, and found $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $s$. The only relationship you missed was $x_3 = s$, which was basically the definition of $s$.

Answer (score 1):

When you "turned it back into an equation " you made an error. You should get: $x_1-13x_3=-10\\x_2+17x_3=11$.  You can choose $x_3$ freely, then solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The solution space is $1$-dimensional.

You get $\{\begin{pmatrix}-10+13s\\11-17s\\s\end{pmatrix}: s\in\Bbb R\}$.